# PHP Browser-Download of files

Tags: php, download, readfile

My problem is that my browser download script writes the file content into the browser and do not download it as a file from the browser.

My provider is Strato. (www.strato.de)

I am using this php script for downloading files:

```
if(file_exists($backup_file_path)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($backup_file_path).'"');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($backup_file_path));
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            readfile($backup_file_path);
            exit;

            echo "<script>console.log('Download success');</script>";
        }
```

At localhost with xampp it is working but at Strato my described issue occurs.

Please help me if you can.
Thank you!

PS:
PHP version: 5.5

Answer (score 0):

I see this... fix this but your issue is another one...

change this:

```
exit;
echo "<script>console.log('Download success');</script>";
```

with this:

```
echo "<script>console.log('Download success');</script>";
exit;
```

I suggest to suppress this line `echo "<script>console.log('Download success');</script>";`, may interferer with download file...

For solving your issue you may want try this...

```
$file = "test.zip";
$downloads_folder = "files/";
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . sprintf("%u", filesize($downloads_folder . $file)));
$fh = fopen($downloads_folder . $file, "rb");
while (!feof($fh)) {
  echo fgets($fh);
  flush();
}
fclose($fh);
exit;
```

Let's me know if works for you, tested, works for me on linux and windows with php 5.4 and 5.6

[Download my file and test it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rbo84zf8qgmjejq/demo_file_download.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! - I tried your version but nothing changed. The same problem as before - The script writes the content into the browser but does not download the file.

Comment: I think that your issue is in your `php.ini` hosted on www.strato.de, For solving your issue you may want to contact your hosting service and ask to open a ticket of assistance. If the script works for you too under Windows the only guilty can be Strato Hosting that has some problem into their `php.ini`. You can compare your `php.ini` on Windows and your `php.ini` on Strato. For this purpose create a php file named info.php and put inside this line `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` then upload on your Strato web space and put the same file on your web space under Windows. See  the `php.ini` differences.